# How to find two unknown components of a vector

Tags: vectors

[image]

I have found the length of AB to be 60m and the angle between AB - BC is 64 degrees but I am unable to find the length of the vector BC with two unknown vector components. I am unable to find much help on the internet.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use pictures.

Answer (score 1):

(c) the vector equation of BC
$r=\begin{pmatrix} 40\\0\\-20 \end{pmatrix} +
\lambda\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\4\\1\end{pmatrix}$ passes through (a,b,$0$)
$\because z=0 \space then \space 0=-20+\lambda\\ \therefore\lambda=20$
$
a=40+20 \times 3\\ \space \space=100\\
b=0+20 \times 4\\ \space \space=80$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You have for the equation of the line through $B$ and $C$:
$$(40,0,-20) + t(3,4,1) = (a,b,0)$$

Now, solve the equation for $t$ using the $z$-coordinate.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand. For every single step in the Z (The last co ordinate) I take 3 steps in the X (First) and 4 steps in the Y (Middle)? If so, I have it :)

Comment: @Zibraz313 : 
Exactly. Or you can set up the equation for the $z$-coordinate: $-20 + t\cdot 1 = 0 \Rightarrow t = 20$ and the substitute this $t$ into the equation.